How many antichains of Bn (Boolean Algebra on n elements) have two elements?
My attempt:
B1 has 0, B2 has 1, B3 has 3, B4 has 6, B5 has 10
I think.... therefore Bn must have ((n-1)(n))/2 antichains with two elements.
Is this correct?

What is the definition of "antichain"?

If a subset S ⊆ P contains no two comparable elements, then S is an antichain.

You have undercounted in some cases, I'm afraid. Consider $B_3$ as the power set of ${a,b,c}.$ Then $\bigl{{a},{b}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{a},{c}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{b},{c}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{a},{b,c}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{b},{a,c}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{c},{a,b}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{a,b},{b,c}\bigr},$ $\bigl{{a,b},{a,c}\bigr},$ and $\bigl{{a,c},{b,c}\bigr}$ are all antichains of $B_3$ with $2$ elements.
